# Create CookieManager instance before initializing webview

Tags: android, webview

I need to call

```
CookieManager.getInstance();
```

before initializing the webview. Earlier it could be done using

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(Context)
```

as mentioned at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

However since CookieSyncManager is deprecated now, what method should I use?

Thanks